# Automated functions in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I was wondering if there is something like a script that I can write on the MongoDB side that would do something like delete an item in a list if it is older than a week old etc.

I want to have the DB do this check every day. Are there some kind of automated functions that I can setup on the DB to do this?

I could just write a few small methods to do it on the userside myself, but I remember my old SQL DB having this feature. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Self-Managed MongoDB, The answer is NO.

Like SQL, MongoDB doesn't support scheduled transactions. However you can run the scheduled jobs in your programming language and perform the operations. For example, https://thecodebarbarian.com/node.js-task-scheduling-with-agenda-and-mongodb

If you are using MongoDB Atlas, Then you need to check this https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/scheduled-triggers/

Answer (score 1):

Then you might want to check out the MongoDB TTL feature :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

It won't run every day like a script, but it will automatically remove data after some time.

Hope it can help !

Comment: This answer was helpful, but the first response is more applicable. Thank you for your help!